# WARN 15720 --- [io-7000-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET /"http"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to built a springboot project and I got stuct with this issue. Whwn I am calling the API localhost:7000/dashboard/project-overview I am getting this error in the chrome:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
this as a fallback.
```

Tue Aug 06 05:19:40 ICT 2019
   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
   No message available

And in the console I am getting this error

```
WARN 7248 --- [nio-7000-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : 
No mapping for GET /dashboard/project-overview
```

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class ViewProjectOverview {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@Column(name="project_name")
private String projectName;

@Column(name="doc_url")
private Clob docUrl;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public Clob getDocUrl() {
    return docUrl;
}

public void setDocUrl(Clob docUrl) {
    this.docUrl = docUrl;
}

public ViewProjectOverview() {
    super();
}
}
```

Here is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface ViewProjectOverviewRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ViewProjectOverview, String> {

}
```

Here is my service

```
@Service
public class ViewProjectOverviewService {

@Autowired
ViewProjectOverviewRepository vpor;

public List<ViewProjectOverview> findAll(){
    return vpor.findAll();
}

}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/dashboard")
public class ViewProjectOverviewController {

@Autowired
ViewProjectOverviewService vpos;

 @GetMapping(path= {"/project-overview" })
 public List<ViewProjectOverview> getAll(){
        return vpos.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Any stacktrace ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Perhaps your `ViewProjectOverviewController` is not being scanned by Spring. What packages are you scanning, and what is the package of `ViewProjectOverviewController`?

Comment: I had added my model, repository and service

Comment: Is the package (ie directory) of your main class a parent package of all your bean class packages, especially your controller class?

Comment: I had check it, my controller located in the same package with other controller and other controller worked.